# How to strike string in an html table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Everytime i search for the word "Javascript" as specified in my code, I can't seem to get that word to be striked out in the table. I don't see why my input is not finding my word i'm searching through the ID.

```js
   <script type = "text/javascript">
         <!--
           
  function findWord(){
  
  var str = document.getElementById("word").value;

  var text = document.getElementById("search").innerHTML;
  text = text.toLowerCase();
  
  
        str = str.trim();
  var n = str.indexOf(str.toLowerCase()); 

  if( n != -1 )
   {
    text = text.replace( str , "<u>"+str+"</u>" ); 
   }
   
   text = text.toUpperCase(); 

   document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = text;

}
```

```html
<table> 
  <tr>
   <td class="wordSearch" id="search">
    
    QMGLUTKVRDIYKSA<br />
    GKMTWRITELNXDYP  <br />
    MGETELEMENTBYID <br /> 
    TTOLOWERCASEBRD <br /> 
    NYRTOUPPERCASEI <br /> 
    CJDYOFUNCTIONPN <br /> 
    WEMSFZTJZJOMFTV <br /> 
    BCBCCXSURWHILEE <br />  
    PPRETURNXATLJOU <br /> 
    OIFYGTVFXHAAVIN <br /> 
    FZRXADXETWINDOW <br />  
    DWNIZKHIVFXPIDL <br />  
    IFRSTRINGVCQQLP <br />
    DOCUMENTULELSEN <br /> 
    JYBOOLEANFAXAJH 
   
   </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
  <form action="">
   <p>
    <label>Enter the word you've found and press Enter:
    <input type="text" id="word" />
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Enter" onclick= "findWord();" />
   </p>
  </form>
  <div id="scoreArea"></div>
```

Comment: `wordSearch` isnt defined, and your code has several syntax errors

Comment: In addition to patrick comment you can use `search()` function in JS

Comment: @AlaaA.F. What is that function? Can you give me some references?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Here is the `search()` function reference : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp || and here is a JS library for adding search functionality and some cool stuf : http://www.listjs.com/

Comment: wordSearch is from the class=wordSearch patrick

Answer (score 0):

this code may help you

```
function findWord(str) {
    var tdText=document.getElementById("search").textContent.trim();
    return tdText.search(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a Jquery plug-in for filter and search in a table like jQuery.FilterTable
[jQuery.FilterTable](https://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/)

Comment: NO jquery is not allowed whatsoever!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few errors here. The first one you'll find on debugging is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: str is not defined
```

This means you're trying to call the strike() function on a variable that hasn't been defined.  You'll first need to get the search value and store it in a variable.

You're html has the input as id="word", so we need to get that from the html.
The command to do this is:

```
document.getElementById("word")
```

And we specifically want the *value* of what they typed in, which is:

```
var str = document.getElementById("word").value
```

Now if they type in "hello" or "javascript", it will be stored in the str variable.  Problem number 1 fixed! Onto the second problem.

```
var inputVal = document.getElementById( "search" );
```

Remember, when you get an Element, it's returning the entire node, not the value stored within it.  Before, we had to use the value command to get the actual text, but if you try that here, it won't work because *search* is a `<td>` element, not an input.  I've never had to get text from a `<td>` before, so I had to look it up using the debugger tools.  (If you're not familiar with them, here's a guide on how to use [chrome's dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). As it turns out, for a td, what you want is either a *innerText* or *innerHTML*.  Looking at what is stored in each, *innerHTML* is the one we would want to use as it gets just the entire html, which will be important later on (*innerText* doesn't get html elements like `<br\>`).

```
var wordSearch = document.getElementById("search").innerHTML;
```

I also, changed the name of the variable you were storing this in from *inputVal* to *wordSearch* as I feel like naming it *inputVal* is a bit confusing as I would presume by that name it was the value inputted by the user, not the value of the wordSearch document.

Ok, now we have the input from the user and the wordSearch, the next troublesome line is this one:

```
wordSearch.elements.value = words.indexOf( inputVal.value=result );
```

I believe you're trying to see if the value the user provided existed somewhere in the wordSearch, which would be the next logical step to take.  So, there's a couple things here. Firstly, again you're referencing variables that haven't been defined, in this case: *wordSearch*.  Based on your comment above, you were using *wordSearch* was from the class name.  Unfortunately, in JavaScript, you can't directly call an element based on it's class like that.  You would need to do something like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("wordSearch")
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this method, because (as a canny observer may have guessed from the name) *getElementsByClassName* returns a *list* of elements, not a specific element (hence the name using "elements" not "element").  That's because multiple elements can have the same class name.  That is why I used the id, instead of the class name to find it earlier. Only a single element can have a particular id.

Secondly, we have the following snippet of code:

```
words.indexOf( inputVal.value=result )
```

This is doing two things. First, it is assigning the results variable to inputVal.value because you have a single equals sign.  If you wanted to compare them, you would need two (==) or three(===).  The second thing it's doing is checking words for the first index of that value.  indexOf return an integer indicating where it was found, and -1 if it wasn't found.  Let's fix this.

```
var locationFound = wordSearch.indexOf(str.toUpperCase());
```

This will give us the location where the search value provided is found in the word search or -1 if it isn't found.  Then you could do something like:

```
if (locationFound === -1) {
  alert(str + " wasn't found");
} else {
  // strike through code goes here
}
```

Now, we'd need to code up the strike through section.

```
var locationEnd = locationFound + str.length;
str = str.strike();
document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = 
        wordSearch.slice(0, locationFound) + 
        str + 
        wordSearch.slice(locationEnd);
```

Ok, this may look a bit confusing, but let's walk through it one line at a time.

```
var locationEnd = locationFound + str.length;
```

This is getting the end point of where the search value was found, which we'll need in a bit.

```
str = str.strike();
```

This is where we do the strike through, replacing the original text.

```
document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = 
        wordSearch.slice(0, locationFound) + 
        str + 
        wordSearch.slice(locationEnd);
```

What this is doing is removing the original word in the document, and replacing it with the struck through version.  It's then setting that value to the innerHTML of the element with the id of search.

The final code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="wordSearch" id="search">

            QMGLUTKVRDIYKSA <br />
            GKMTWRITELNXDYP <br />
            MGETELEMENTBYID <br />  
            TTOLOWERCASEBRD <br />  
            NYRTOUPPERCASEI <br />  
            CJDYOFUNCTIONPN <br />  
            WEMSFZTJZJOMFTV <br />  
            BCBCCXSURWHILEE <br />      
            PPRETURNXATLJOU <br />  
            OIFYGTVFXHAAVIN <br />  
            FZRXADXETWINDOW <br />      
            DWNIZKHIVFXPIDL <br />      
            IFRSTRINGVCQQLP <br />
            DOCUMENTULELSEN <br />  
            JYBOOLEANFAXAJH 

        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <form action="">
        <p>
            <label>Enter the word you've found and press Enter:
            <input type="text" id="word" />
            </label>
            <input type="button" value="Enter" onclick= "findWord();" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <div id="scoreArea"></div>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var words = "Javascript";
    function findWord() {
        var str = document.getElementById("word").value.toUpperCase();
        var wordSearch = document.getElementById("search").innerHTML;

        var locationFound = wordSearch.indexOf(str);

        if (locationFound === -1) {
          alert(str + " wasn't found");
        } else {
          var locationEnd = locationFound + str.length;
          str = str.strike();
          document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = 
                  wordSearch.slice(0, locationFound) + 
                  str + 
                  wordSearch.slice(locationEnd);
        }

    }
</script>
```